# Visual Studio 2005 Debugging: Generating MAP file| Crash Dump

Tags: visual-studio, dictionary, linker

Hi all I am running Visual2005 and want to generate the MAP file to analyze the
crash situation.

I have enabled below settings.

```
Linker->Generate MAP    - Yes (/DEBUG)
General Debugging Info  - Yes (/MAP)
```

And making the application crash by writing it in the NULL location.

If I run the EXE With VS2005 it is generating the MAP file in the path of EXE.

If I run the EXE out side the VS2005 application is crashing but no MAP file generated.

Do I need to do any other setting to generate the MAP file.

**Edit:** I need to analyze the crashing occuring in client location we will give them a debugg version of EXE and when it crashes they will send us the DUMP which we can analyze.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, MAP file is created by linker and not at runtime. Do you need map file or crash dump? These are two different things.

If you want to add crash dump capability to your program, you need MiniDumpWriteDump
function and global exception handler. Then you can make post-mortem debugging, using crash dump generated by the program. See details here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx

Regarding map file, you only need crash address, and then you can try to find source code line by this address and map file. This technique doesn't work in many cases, post-mortem debugging is much better.

Edit. Well, you need a crash dump, this is a good decision. Using map files is not reliable. By default, Windows user mode program does not create crash dump. This feature must be added manually. CodeProject article describes how to do this, and shows how to make post-mortem debugging.